# BaseController SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller

In my project I am forced to create a class with Base Controller which handles errors. I would like to ask whether there is a way of making it really **"MAIN" Controller** except attaching to all classes `extends BaseController`. I mean, some tricky changes in configuration files or maybe useful Annotations. Is **extends BaseController** attached to all classes definition the only way of solving that problem?

Comment: Same question here. I'd like to see exception handlers (@ExceptionHandler) automatically scanned with no need to define them in a specific controller.

Answer (score 1):

[`@ControllerAdvice`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) (since 3.2.0) will meet your needs.

For Spring @MVC features required to all controllers in your application, please consider using [`@ControllerAdvice`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotation.
This is introduced since Spring 3.2.0, and extremely useful for globally handling exceptions from @MVC handlers. From javadoc:

> It is typically used to define `@ExceptionHandler`, `@InitBinder`, and
>   `@ModelAttribute` methods that apply to all `@RequestMapping` methods.

BTW, I don't think using a sort of `BaseController` is a good design. But it might be a good workaround for similar functionality for lower version of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with implementing your own [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers-resolver)?

I think that it boils down to:

- @ExceptionHandler = within a given controller
- HandlerExceptionResolver = whole application